# How to save text clips to insert into emails (eg, NOT email templates)?

Tags: gmail

I'm looking for a way to **insert saved content into an email in Gmail**, but I'm having trouble searching for solutions because gmail templates (which I do not want to use) dominate the search space.

This is what I want to accomplish (see also screenshot below from Hubspot):

- Create a 'snippit' of text, links, images, etc
- Inside an email, select the snippet you want and insert it

This is particularly valuable for things that I use semi-frequently, but take a long time to find each time (URLs to our slack login page, etc).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This isn't specific to gmail, but [Text Blaze](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/text-blaze/idgadaccgipmpannjkmfddolnnhmeklj/related?hl=en-US) seems like a possible solution. It's a bit overkill, but it works in any text field in chrome, which is nice.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing things on a single computer, and only need a small number of snippets, then look into clipboard managers. The built-in one in Windows, for instance, lets you pin items for re-use later.